# How to use the mysql2 js library ? syntax to interpolate in a subquery INSERT statement?

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

I have been banging my head on this issue and the 'usual semantic lookup tool suspects' (google and *others*) have been of no help

Specifically, I am using `mysql2/promise` library and attempting to complete a successful `INSERT` statement that looks like this:

```js
const query = `INSERT INTO sso_user (user_id,username,user_status,organization_id) VALUES ?, (select organization_id from organization where organization_name= ?)`;
const [rows] = await conn.query(query, [valueArray]);
```

the `valueArray` looks something like:

```
[["uuid_t349199e","testuser@test.io","active","my sample org"] ]
```

And of course, I am attempting to insert a user record whose `organization_id` value looks up to an existing organization value.

I have been able to successfully complete this transaction written out as a normal query, however I keep getting various binding and straight up obscure "error at position 279" errors

Is this interpolation for an INSERT query that also includes a subquery lookup even possible in the `mysql2/promise` library?

*Edit* I should add I have *also* attempted variations of specifying the number of `?` that match each value, and I have had no luck there as well

*Edit2* this is an example error message that is somewhat constructive when I attempt to run the insert query with enumerated `?` characters

`Error: target: core.-.primary: vttablet: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = missing bind var v1 (CallerID: auhldnxzu7h15g8j56ms)`

Comment: Why do you want to copy data between the tables? Data redundancy (too often) leads to inconsistency.

Comment: @jarlh interesting question, I am not actually trying to copy data, I am trying to insert `users` that are correctly associated with their respective `organization` parent tables. I was trying to use the "subquery" approach so I dont have to do extra logic to retrieve and assign the orgs UUID values

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a sub `SELECT` query for a single column since it could return multiple rows.

Instead, construct the sub query to return a combination of your static and dynamic values

```js
const query =
  'INSERT INTO sso_user (organization_id, user_id, username, user_status) ' +
  'SELECT organization_id, ? FROM organization WHERE organization_name = ?';
const results = await Promise.all(
  valueArray.map(([uid, un, s, on]) => conn.query(query, [[uid, un, s], on])),
);
```

According to [the docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql?tab=readme-ov-file#escaping-query-values), the `[uid, un, s]` array should be treated as a list, creating a sub-query like

```sql
SELECT organization_id, 'uuid_t349199e', 'testuser@test.io', 'active'
FROM organization WHERE organization_name = 'my sample org'
```

Comment: thanks @Phil I think you could solve the "returns multiple rows" problem by adding a `LIMIT 1` but I understand that's besides the point.